# Splitting row data into columns in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as per the below.

```
ID  Party   Votes

RS-24   D   31

RS-24   R   12
```

What I'd like to do is split the row data into a new column as per the below so that I can run some basic calculations.

```
ID  D_Votes R_Votes

RS-24   31  12
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could go about this?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is also a classic case for `pivot`: `df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Party', values='Votes').add_suffix('_Votes')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` and `unstack`

```
df1=df.set_index(['ID','Party']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
df1.columns=df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1
Out[253]: 
       D_Votes  R_Votes
ID                     
RS-24       31       12
```